# Is it possible to make an AJAX request in Redux?

Tags: ajax, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux. I tried different methods but I am not able to get ajax request in redux from server. Can you please tell me is there any middleware or other way to make an AJAX call through Redux ?

Comment: [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is the simplest. But I recommend redux-saga.

Comment: Ok Thank you @dwjohnston for the information. Will surely read about both of them.

Comment: You are looking at the things in the wrong way. Redux is a state management library, it has nothing to do with ajax. I suggest to understand redux better first and then you'll know how to pass data from ajax to state (and why).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the suggestion @MrBr